# Windows 11 Canary Channel: explorer.exe not working

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, crash, windows-insider

I ran ExplorerPatcher on my Windows laptop then force stopped it as explorer.exe unexpectedly shut down. explorer.exe didn't boot up using Task Manager, nor after restart, nor in Safe Mode, nor when I reinstalled Windows 11 (Canary Channel) using the 'keep personal files and apps' option. How could I restore my laptop to a working state without deleting my personal files or apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading the ExplorerPatcher installer using command line to uninstall:

- Ctrl+Shift+Esc to open Task Manager
- *Run new task*, run `powershell`
- In the command line window, switch to a safe directory like D:\ : `cd D:\`
- Download the installer from GitHub: `curl.exe -L -o ep_setup.exe https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/releases/download/22621.1555.55.2_6fb998e/ep_setup.exe`
- Run the installer to uninstall: `.\ep_setup.exe /uninstall`
- After uninstalling, `explorer.exe` to restore the desktop.

Answer (score 6):

Explorer Patcher does binary patching of Windows. As the source code for
Windows is not public property, this is based on disassembler techniques
and some guessing, but never, never, on the complete knowledge of the
software that's being patched (only Microsoft has that knowledge).

Such strong-arm modification may work, or may have unforeseen effects,
*as long as that Windows software hasn't changed*.
Once the software being patched has changed in a later version of Windows,
the patching may miss the mark and cause the patched binaries to
malfunction in unpredictable ways.

It's a very bad idea to use Explorer Patcher on a new version of Windows
for which it was not verified.

I advise to never use such software, unless one is willing to take the
risk of reinstalling Windows to undo the patches.

Comment: Before I manually backup (I've found that the _Open..._ menu in apps does work, so I'll have to use that) and downgrade to Windows 10, do you have any suggestions that might restore the system without a full wipe of my data?

Comment: I believe that Windows 11 and 10 are similar enough that you can do [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) or use the [Media Creation Tool](https://pureinfotech.com/downgrade-windows-11-10/). Mind your backups, just in case.

Comment: A decent patcher should have done some sort of hash or similar to check and make sure it was patching a file that is known to work.

Comment: @trlkly: Another possibility is using some heuristic to locate the right spot to patch, which might succeed or not.

Comment: but does it *really* do binary patching, in the sense that it modifies the contents of executables and binary libraries? looking at the github sourcecode shows that it seems to limit itself to policies, the registry, shell interaction using the api, hooks, and calling into existing executables.

Comment: @dlatikay: It has destroyed enough Windows installations on our site to be sure that it's far from harmless.

Answer (score 4):

Explorer Patcher is a hack for Windows Explorer. Everything I have read says (1) it does not work well (Windows 11 Explorer and Task Bar are not highly customizable) and (2) may be difficult to uninstall.

See this article where the OP said they had to reinstall Windows 11 to get rid of it.

[Explorer Patcher issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1192677/windows-11-pro-and-explorer-patcher)

Comment: More importantly Explorer Patcher might not be compatible with Insider Preview builds, eventually it will work, but that isn’t something we can help with.